# What is the Java type at runtime for a Kotlin function type?

Tags: java, kotlin

If I have the Kotlin method bellow and call it from Java, what is the return type that I get in Java?

```
fun ff(): (Int, Int) -> Int {
    return { x, y -> x + y }
}
```

Comment: The return type will be a function, taking 2 int in parameters, and returning an int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Kotlin function types `(T1, ..., TN) -> R` are represented by the `FunctionN<T1, ..., TN, R>` types of the Kotlin runtime.

There is a [specification document](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/spec-docs/function-types.md) describing this aspect of the language design at its current state.

It says, in particular, that there are 23 function types from `Function0` to `Function22` in the Kotlin runtime for JVM (shipped as the `kotlin-runtime` library), looking like this:

```
package kotlin.jvm.functions

interface Function1<in P1, out R> : kotlin.Function<R> {
    fun invoke(p1: P1): R
}
```

The extension function types `TR.(T1, ..., TN) -> R` have the same runtime representation as normal functional types with the receiver prepended to the parameters list, namely `(TR, T1, ..., TN) -> R`.

Functions with more than 22 parameters are represented at runtime by a single type:

```
package kotlin.jvm.functions

interface FunctionN<out R> : kotlin.Function<R> {
    val arity: Int
    fun invokeVararg(vararg p: Any?): R
}
```

In Kotlin/JS, functional values are represented in the way that is natural to JS, i.e. they are compiled to a function definition and a reference to it:

```
function main$lambda(s1, s2) {
    println(s1 + s2);
    return Unit;
}

function main(args) {
    var f = main$lambda;
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Could you expand your answer and include how Javascript would see the same return type?

Comment: @dilvan, I'm not quite sure about the runtime representation, but in the compiled JS, functional values are compiled to something like `function main$lambda(s1, s2) { ... }; var f = main$lambda`